# CGI show with Rock Men, Ice Men, and Fire Men, and planets that moved?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Does anyone remember the name of a CGI show that had Rock Men, Ice Men, and Fire Men? It had planets that moved and were cannons as well. I used to watch it with my dad when I was younger, but now I can't remember the name.

Comment: adding an answer. this was my favorite show as a child when it aired :)

Comment: Since the OP has [commented](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86149/cgi-show-with-rock-men-ice-men-and-fire-men-and-planets-that-moved/86154?noredirect=1#comment188328_86154) that the answer below is correct, I've closed it as a dupe

Answer (score 6):

[Shadow Raiders - War Planets](https://youtu.be/WXDH2NUYrgg)

You can see the "Rock Men, Ice Men and Fire Men" in this intro of the show.

"Shadow Raiders is set in a five-planet solar system known as the Cluster. The four habitable planets are in a constant state of war, always raiding one another for resources unique to each planet. However, when an alien named Tekla comes from another solar system, she brings a warning: the Beast Planet is coming. Now Graveheart, a humble miner of Planet Rock, must convince the leaders of Fire, Rock, Bone, and Ice to put aside their differences and stand together against the Beast, their new common enemy."